# How to compare 2 columns in excel

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula, formula

I have Column A and Column B. What I want to do is copy Column C and remove rows which match/contain rows in Column B.

I have this formula but it doesn't remove containing rows, only matching:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISNA(MATCH(A:A,B:B,0)),A:A,""))
```

Any formula/query for this?

You can see it live here (please comment suggestion there): https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1EBJgRAt0UfyfP_zgv3RITNnN3VW3KXoeiIC9mDTjJL4/edit?usp=sharing

[image]

Comment: B3, is the vaule "sevda" or "sevdaa"?

Comment: Have you tried [`FIND()`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094126?vid=1-635784654137169952-3214806097) instead of `MATCH()`?

Comment: @imtheman i count make "find" work.

Comment: @pnuts google. see it here https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1EBJgRAt0UfyfP_zgv3RITNnN3VW3KXoeiIC9mDTjJL4/edit#gid=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set the formula in column c row 1 as "=if(a1 = b1,1,0)", then you could just filter on values in column c = 1 and delete those rows. That way when you copy column c to another column or where ever else you are copying the data, you will not get the matching items to copy over.

Comment: Another thing you could do is to use a COUNTIF function to see if the value in column A shows up anywhere in column B. So then you would use "=if(COUNTIF($B$1:$B$300, a1) > 0,1,0)" as a formula in column c. Then delete all the 1's.

Comment: The formulas you send do it only for one row, I need to compare any value in A to any value in B (not in order)

Comment: So then you would use a second COUNTIF function as an argument to the if function. Again in column c row 1 put "=if(COUNTIF($B$1:$B$300, a1) + COUNTIF($A$1:$A$300,b1) > 0,1,0)". The thing to remember about my formula is you have to fill down for the relevant range and here I assumed 300 rows only.

Answer (score 1):

Excel - Copy column A to C - Highlight columns B & C - Home - Conditional Formatting - Highlight Cells Rules - Duplicate Values - Light Red Fill with Dark Red Text - Sort on pink cell colors for column C - Delete values shaded pink in column C - Done