# Remove duplicates in one column based on a date in another column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an excel spreadsheet with two columns:
Column A contains a list of names and Column B contains dates.

I want to get rid of duplicate entries based on dates.
This is an example

```
A     B

John  01/03/2020

John  01/03/2020 

Bob   01/03/2020

John  02/03/2020

Bob   02/03/2020

Bob   02/03/2020
```

I want to remove duplicates that have the same date, so the final result should be:

```
A     B

John  01/03/2020

Bob   01/03/2020

John  02/03/2020

Bob   02/03/2020
```

Comment: i think you could try VBA

Comment: Could this be a duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32704059/how-to-compare-2-columns-in-excel/32704372#32704372

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why aren't you using the standard `Remove duplicates` functionality?

[image]

Comment: I tried this and it works on a simple list but it didn't work on my real list. Does it need to be ordered by date?

Comment: Then post your real list.

Comment: @acaselli did you check only the name and date columns?

Comment: @acaselli No, the sorting is not required.

Comment: I think I found the error. My dates contain also the time (with seconds) so, of course, the list won't have any duplicates. I'll try again but I think that will fix it.

Answer (score 0):

If you decide to use VBA try:

```
Sub test()

    Dim i As Long, y As Long, Lastrow As Long
    Dim strName As String
    Dim dtDate As Date

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        Lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

        For i = Lastrow To 1 Step -1

            For y = i - 1 To 1 Step -1
                If (.Range("A" & i).Value = .Range("A" & y).Value) And (.Range("B" & i).Value = .Range("B" & y).Value) Then
                    .Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
                End If

            Next y

        Next i

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Than you, I tried but it didn't work. I created a button, assigned the macro, clicked on the button but it didn't remove all the duplicates.